# Short story about astronauts that cut off their hand

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, andre-norton

As I remember correctly this story was written by Andre Norton, and be titled something like "Purple Hand." They cut one hand off, leaving one to drive the spaceship. I can't find anything in Google about this story.

Comment: If you want to add anything please [edit] your question to include those details.

Comment: Closest title match I've found for Andre Norton is *Firehand*, fifth book in the Time Traders series.

Comment: There was a character in one of (the last of) Varley's "Hotline" stories who had removed one arm and the opposite leg (including most of the shoulder and pelvis on those), mainly for style but also to have tunnels around her ship that she could traverse but others could not.

Comment: Why they had to cut off their hand?